# How to let libpng16.so.16 use libz.so.1 in the local directory ? (Another ZLIB_1.2.9 issue)

Tags: django, anaconda, zlib

When I run a django project, I got the following error:

ImportError: /lib64/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/./libpng16.so.16)

I found that that directory /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/./ already contains a correct version of
libz.so.1,

libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.11

But it seems that libpng16.so.16 is using libz.so.1 in /usr/lib64.

How to let libpng16.so.16 use libz.so.1 in the local directory ?
Is this related to Anaconda library setting ?

Comment: How can you say a symlink to `1.2.11` is the correct version if the error says `ZLIB_1.2.9`?

Comment: Either way: how did you install Anaconda? Which version? Why do you need to use Anaconda for your Django project instead of regular Python?

Comment: @AKX Thank you for the comments. "How can you say a symlink to 1.2.11 is the correct version if the error says ZLIB_1.2.9", because if I did a symbolic link of /usr/lib64/libz.so.1 to /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/./ libz.so.1.2.11, then the Django project will run.  (But I do no want to mess system library /usr/lib64/libz.so.1. I learnt a painful lesson).

Comment: I agree: don't manipulate files in Conda manually or create additional symlinks. Users encounter these issues when they [mix channels](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html#using-multiple-channels). Either use only `anaconda` or only `conda-forge` channel in a given environment. If you would like a more precise diagnosis of the issue consider sharing the `conda list` output for the environment.